# How to sort integers alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, alphabetical-sort

How can I sort integers alphabetically? Like this:

```
integers = [10, 1, 101, 2, 111, 212, 100000, 22, 222, 112, 10101, 1100, 11, 0]
```

printed like this on Python console

```
[0, 1, 10, 100000, 101, 10101, 11, 1100, 111, 112, 2, 212, 22, 222]
```

I have tried this

```
def sort_integers(integers):
    return sorted(integers)
```

but I guess you have to do it this way

```
def sort_integers(integers):
    return sorted(integers, key = lambda....... )
```

I just don't know to what to write after the lambda?

Answer (score 29):

```
sorted(integers, key=str)

->
[0, 1, 10, 100000, 101, 10101, 11, 1100, 111, 112, 2, 212, 22, 222]
```

Explanation: `str` is a function that casts the integers into strings. Since `sorted` sorts strings alphabetically by default this does exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 11):

You can simply use `str` as `key`:

```
sorted(integers,key=str)
```

So here for each element, the `str` function is called, which converts the `int` into a `str`ing. That itself is not spectacular. But the *comparison* of strings is different: it sorts lexicographically.

```
>>> sorted([0, 1, 10, 100000, 101, 10101, 11, 1100, 111, 112, 2, 212, 22, 222],key=str)
[0, 1, 10, 100000, 101, 10101, 11, 1100, 111, 112, 2, 212, 22, 222]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sort your integers lexicographically as if they were strings, you can tell Python to treat them as strings while sorting:

```
>>> integers = [10, 1, 101, 2, 111, 212, 100000, 22, 222, 112, 10101, 1100, 11, 0]
>>> sorted(integers, key=lambda n: str(n))
[0, 1, 10, 100000, 101, 10101, 11, 1100, 111, 112, 2, 212, 22, 222]
>>>
```

But you actually don't even have to have the `lambda n: ...` part either. You can simply pass the `str` function as the `key` and Python will know what to do. calling `str(n)` where `n` is each element in your list:

```
>>> sorted(integers, key=str)
[0, 1, 10, 100000, 101, 10101, 11, 1100, 111, 112, 2, 212, 22, 222]
>>>
```

So your function would end up being:

```
def sort_integers(integers):
    return sorted(integers, key=str)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
list(map(int, (sorted(str(i) for i in integers))))
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 10, 100000, 101, 10101, 11, 1100, 111, 112, 2, 212, 22, 222]
```

Comment: But he wants the resulting list as an integer.

Comment: Your sorted call does not need to do what it is doing either. Similar to the rest of the answers just pass your list with a key argument.

Comment: that is the better answer, but this works and it was what i originally wrote. I just didn't know about the key arg

Answer (score 0):

Try a [Most Significant Digit Radix Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Most_significant_digit_radix_sorts). This avoids having to convert the integers to strings, but is tougher to implement unless you use a library or other prewritten [code](https://gist.github.com/nlguillemot/3093825).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.