# How can I sort string with characters and numbers in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort following things

```
l = ["125.13-ac35", "142.1532-afe354eqd", "125.13-abe319ej", "142.1523-d315aw"]
```

like this using Python.

```
l = ["125.13-abe319ej", "125.13-ac35",  "142.1523-d315aw", "142.1532-afe354eqd"]
```

Someone suggested me to use radix sort, but that doesn't work as I wanted.
For example, to sort those things, following list

```
a = [15, 3216, 120, 1, 1000, 253]
```

should be sorted like this

```
a = [1, 1000, 120, 15, 253, 3216]
```

Is there any sorting algorithm to sort like that?

Comment: The duplicate is wrong. This question is not a duplicate of [Is there a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort). In fact, it is asking for the exact opposite - how to **avoid** sorting numbers in increasing order. Instead, it is a duplicate of [How to sort integers alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835964/how-to-sort-integers-alphabetically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to sort the list by converting the inner element to string

```
a = [15, 3216, 120, 1, 1000, 253]
a.sort(key=lambda x:str(x))

print(a)
```

output

```
[1, 1000, 120, 15, 253, 3216]
```

Comment: I know I'm not allowed to say thanks in comments, but that was a quick and good answer. works like a charm, thank you so much

Comment: thanks, you are allowed to say

Comment: You can write directly `a.sort(key=str)`. No need for an extra layer of lambda.

Comment: The comment text box says "Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks"" because comments like "+1" or "thanks" don't add anything and [should not be posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258004/1364007).

Comment: (also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment fore more)